# OutOfMemoryError [memory exhasted] Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, out-of-memory

```
public class CarBP extends Activity {


List<String> brakesList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ListView brakesListView;
public static int p;
public ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
public String carT;
DataBaseHelper myd;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
    setContentView(R.layout.carbp);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    carT = bundle.getString("carT");
    myd = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    brakesList = myd.readData(carT);
    //TextView cartext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cartypetext);
    //cartext.setText(carT.toUpperCase());
    brakesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brakesList);
    brakesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    brakesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            p = position;
            Intent intent = new Intent(CarBP.this, BrakeDetails.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

public static String getSelectedBake()
{
    return brakesListView.getItemAtPosition(p).toString();
}



}
```

Error

08-12 07:04:53.828    6229-6229/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.m.probrake, PID: 6229
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Databasehelper Function

```
public List<String> readData(String carType)
{

    List<String> brakesL = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String lang = "";

    try{

        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Car FROM Cartype INNER JOIN Brakes On Cartype.PBnbr = Brakes.PB_Number WHERE Car_Brand = " + "'" + carType + "'", null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            while(cursor.moveToFirst())
                brakesL.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Car")));

        }

    }finally {

        cursor.close();
    }


     return brakesL;

}
```

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: oops when i remove 
myd = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    brakesList = myd.readData(carT);
the error goes
I added my function DatabaseHelper

Answer (score 0):

The error was with my function:
the while statement should be

```
do {
                brakesL.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Car")));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```